# Как убрать вывод произвольного поля в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

функция `the_content();` выводит пост со всеми произвольными полями, указанными при редактировании поста в админке. Как запретить вывод ненужного произвольного поля в посте на странице публикации?

Comment: В первый раз такое слышу, вы имеете ввиду поля ACF?

Answer (score 0):

```
delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'metafield', '');
```

вытаскивает указанное метаполе и удаляет его. Работает в цикле Wordpress и устанавливать нужно перед `the_content()`

Comment: какую-то вы муть предлагаете